# Replace one character in front of text in file name powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, rename, file-rename

I am trying to rename a big batch of folders with powershell.

I have the folders in this format:

2009.10.11.Name

and I want to change that to:

2009.10.11 Name

I cant find a working way to just target the . in front of the Name. Pleas help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-replace` regex operator:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem . -Directory |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(?<=^\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d)\.',' '}
```